# What workflow should I follow to use and update a Pimcore instance in multiple computers, while using GIT?

Tags: git, git-workflow, pimcore

I want to be able to use and update a Pimcore instance, in multiple computers, while using GIT as version control.

Is there a recommended workflow for in Pimcore (version 4, if it helps) regarding updates and GIT?

In a GIT repository, should I track the pimcore/ folder? and the vendor/ folder?

Either way, what do I have to do to update Pimcore:

1. Can I update in my pc, commit, and then push the modified pimcore/ and vendor/ folders to other development/production systems? Will it work?

Or

2. Should I update each instance of Pimcore, and then in some arcane way hope that each pimcore/ and vendor/ folder ends up being the same?

Is there a better option? What workflow do you think is the best?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It won't work, because updating the source code is not enough. You might also need to update your DB schema, configuration etc. based on the update scripts located at https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/tree/master/update.

You could run these scripts manually, but there is a live updater in the pimcore administration (Tools -> Update) which does this for you together with updating pimcore source code (composer libs in /vendor included). Or if you like, you can update via pimcore console tool, see `php pimcore/cli/console.php update --help`.

So, I would suggest to .gitignore the /vendor and /pimcore folders and update via the live updater or console tool on each computer separately.

Regards,

Martin

Comment: What if I need to add 3rd party code to /vendor ? Or should I leave the /vendor management to the  composer.json and only add 3rd party code via composer? 

I am not sure that this composer solution will mean that all my /vendor code will be the same in each computer

Comment: I would suggest to always add 3rd party code via composer, or at least load it via composer and place it outside the /vendor folder so you can exclude /vendor from your vcs. Pimcore also merges the composer.json when updating, so you won't lose you changes.